# SVG background image with raster parts

Tags: css, vector, svg, background-image, raster

I'm having a strange problem with using an SVG as a background image. Basically I have an image with mostly vector sprites on it with the exception of a couple of raster parts.

The problem is that in Safari (seems fine everywhere else) the raster parts are not displayed at all.

Does anyone know if there is a known problem with what I'm trying to do here? Is it not advisable to mix vector with raster? I'm more curious than anything because I can easily just move the raster parts into a separate image but it's just annoying that it works everywhere except Safari.

One of the images in question (Pin is vector, map is raster. Pin displays fine, map not visible):

[image: SVG01]

Thanks,
Andy

Comment: Is the raster within the svg image embedded as a data uri or an external file?

Comment: It's embedded so it shouldn't be that it can't find the image (especially as it works in other browsers).

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question Andy. Is it possible for you to vectorize the raster areas? ( trace in Illustrator for example ) If not, my answer would be to use a sprite sheet for svg's and one for the raster images, png file...

Comment: Thanks Chris. I think it would be quite hard to trace well as it's a small map snippet. I've added an screenshot to my original post.